# PLPGSQL cursor loop dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function and part of the function is next cursor. I have problem with it because I didn't write it correctly. I am trying to select from a table but the table name is inside a variable,  `stat`. What is wrong ?

```
DECLARE

C_Procedure_Name   CONSTANT   varchar(30) := 'change_constraints';
V_Step                        real := 0;
all_constraints CURSOR(**stat** text) FOR
       SELECT * FROM **stat**  WHERE  constraint_schema = 'report';
.....
```

error : relation stat does not exist
help please...

Note: I am migrating this function from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

Comment: please add your error text

Comment: relation "stat" does not exist

Comment: Why is this question tagged for both Oracle and Postgresql?

Comment: Im migrating this func from oracle. Mybe the solution is simillar in oracle..

Comment: the syntax above looks oracle. Postgres dynamis sql would require `execute format()`

Comment: You can try OPEN FOR documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: I solved this issue with the next code : v_sql_dynamic := 'SELECT * FROM ' || con  ;
    FOR cons IN EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the next piece of code to solve this issue :

```
v_sql_dynamic := 'SELECT * FROM ' || stat  ;
FOR cons IN EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic
```